# duplicate symbol with a third party lib for arm64. ok with armv7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to integrate an ad network called 'adsmogo' http://adsmogo.com/. 
I got duplicate symbol error for arm64, but it's ok with armv7. 
I checked all similar questions on stackoverflow, but no one solved my problem.

```
duplicate symbol l108 in:
    /Users/xxxxxx/Desktop/mm/mm/AdsMoGoLib/AdsMoGoSDK/libAdsMogo.a(AdMoGoView.o)
    /Users/xxxxx/Desktop/mm/mm/AdsMoGoLib/AdsMoGoSDK/libAdsMogo.a(AdsMogoMraidJSBridge.o)
ld: 403 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

You need to do this:

Click on your project (targets)
Click on Build Settings
Under Library Search Paths, delete the paths
May be this will help you.

**Solution 2**

You have duplicate symbol method which means there are duplicate file in project

In your Target's Build Phase, under "Compile Sources" check if there are duplicate file and delete one if you have duplication.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: from the error message, it is 'libAdsMogo' conflicting with itself. But there is only one lib file

Comment: Delete your file from search path remove it from project and then add it again.

Comment: Set build architecture to no under your build  settings

Comment: @OMGPOP if my answer is help to you please mark it as answer .

Comment: you mean build active architecture to NO?

Comment: not working. there are absolutely no duplicate files from compile sources

Comment: Yes build architecture to NO